# Deny access to files except program?

Tags: php, vb.net, .htaccess

I'm coding a program in VB.net which will read/write to a .php & .ini files in my web server. What I want is to restrict people from seeing it. E.g. If someone types "" he doesn't see anything / error. But VB.net can still access it! Can you tell me how to do it? I have tried

```
deny from all
```

but it didn't work, it restricted the access from everything!

Comment: have the vb program update the files using ftp. Or are you using like `PUT` to update?

Answer (score 1):

Your server does not know what has initiated the HTTP request. All it knows is that it has received a knock on the door. The User-Agent supposedly tells the server what is connecting, but that is easily spoofed.

You need to set up an authentication scheme, so your VB program can submit credentials that are not known to anyone else. If you are using the .NET HTTP classes such as HttpWebRequest, look at the Credentials property.